# Flutter Curve Bar

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I wonder if there is a better solution for making a curved bar like the following image.

[image]

Here is my flutter code:

```
import 'package:flutter_web/material.dart';

class CurvedBar extends StatelessWidget {
    const CurvedBar({
      Key key,
    }) : super(key: key);

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Container(height: 50,
      color: Colors.orange,
      child:  Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(20.0)),
            child: Container(
              height: 20.0,
              width: double.infinity,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
         Container(
           color: Colors.white,
           child:  Row( 
            children: <Widget>[
              Flexible(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius:
                        BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(20.0)),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 20.0,
                      color: Colors.orange,
                    ),
                  )),
              Flexible(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius:
                        BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0)),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 20.0,
                      color: Colors.orange,
                    ),
                  ))
            ],
          ))
        ],
      ));
    }
  }
```

Comment: use a custom `ShapeBorder` (a class that extends `ShapeBorder`)?

Comment: @pskink I checked samples of this class but I still don't know how to achieve the same result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make a custom `ShapeBorder` class like this one (the key method is `_getPath` that returns your shape's `Path`):

```
class CustomShapeBorder extends ShapeBorder {
  const CustomShapeBorder();

  @override
  Path getInnerPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) => _getPath(rect);

  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) => _getPath(rect);

  _getPath(Rect rect) {
    final r = rect.height / 2;
    final radius = Radius.circular(r);
    final offset = Rect.fromCircle(center: Offset.zero, radius: r);
    return Path()
      ..moveTo(rect.topLeft.dx, rect.topLeft.dy)
      ..relativeArcToPoint(offset.bottomRight, clockwise: false, radius: radius)
      ..lineTo(rect.center.dx - r, rect.center.dy)
      ..relativeArcToPoint(offset.bottomRight, clockwise: true, radius: radius)
      ..relativeArcToPoint(offset.topRight, clockwise: true, radius: radius)
      ..lineTo(rect.centerRight.dx - r, rect.centerRight.dy)
      ..relativeArcToPoint(offset.topRight, clockwise: false, radius: radius)
      ..addRect(rect);
  }

  @override
  EdgeInsetsGeometry get dimensions {
    return EdgeInsets.all(0);
  }

  @override
  ShapeBorder scale(double t) {
    return CustomShapeBorder();
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) {
  }
}
```

now you can use it like:

```
    Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 80),
      height: 50,
      width: double.infinity,
      decoration: ShapeDecoration(
        shape: CustomShapeBorder(),
        //color: Colors.orange,
        gradient:
            LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.orange]),
        shadows: [
          BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black, offset: Offset(3, -3), blurRadius: 3),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: @pspkink how did you figure out the solution... I mean what I need to learn to be able to make any custom shape I imagine ?

Comment: well done!! - it seems that you implemented rest of the methods...the result looks pretty nice, doesn't it? btw i dont understand `paint` method in `ShapeBorder` as it seems that even with empty `paint` method body the shape is drawn!! and how i figure out the solution? it is simple `Path` manipulations... ;-)

Comment: ok, it seems i got it now: `paint()` is called after the shape is drawn so that you can draw some extra stuff on top of it

Comment: yes I got a better idea..by the way, my original screenshot is flutter web

Comment: and does `CustomShapeBorder` work on flutter web? i tested it on flutter (linux) desktop ;-)

Comment: I think it will work but still, by the end of this year flutter web will be mature.