# How do you clip GestureDetector (or InkWell) input Area with a path?

Tags: flutter

I've created a custom drawn widget using CustomPaint that has a path as an outline. But wrapping the widget in a GestureDetector makes the click area a rectangle around the whole canvas, Is there a way to clip the GestureDetector so that that click only works within the path?

Comment: you dont have to do *anything* if you use a custom `Shape3Border` class, like: `class SB extends ShapeBorder { ...` - sample code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56726277/2252830)

Comment: The package `touchable` https://github.com/nateshmbhat/touchable , is the perfect choice for this. You can give all kinds of gesture callbacks to individual shapes you draw on the canvas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement the `hitTest` method from the `CustomPainter`, add your `Path` there and use the condition `path.contains(position)` to ensure the touch only covers the Path part.

```
class MyCustomPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    // TODO: implement paint
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    // TODO: implement shouldRepaint
    return null;
  }

  @override
  bool hitTest(Offset position) {
    Path path = Path();
    //add your lines/curves here
    path.close();
    return path.contains(position);
  }
}
```

More info about `bool hitTest(Offset position)`:

> Called whenever a hit test is being performed on an object that is
>   using this custom paint delegate.
>
> The given point is relative to the same coordinate space as the last
>   [paint] call.
>
> The default behavior is to consider all points to be hits for
>   background painters, and no points to be hits for foreground painters.
>
> Return true if the given position corresponds to a point on the drawn
>   image that should be considered a "hit", false if it corresponds to a
>   point that should be considered outside the painted image, and null to
>   use the default behavior.

I answered a similar question here: [Flutter: What is the correct way to detect touch enter, move and exit on CustomPainter objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56814862/flutter-what-is-the-correct-way-to-detect-touch-enter-move-and-exit-on-customp/56815041#56815041)